# My Visual Studio extension MSI installer does nothing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm having a go at creating my first Visual Studio extension. Nothing fancy: runs a few external commands, a dialog box or two, simple.

Now that I've finished my extension I want to deploy it. So I created a Setup project (following the instructions provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393694.aspx)), making sure that the default output of my extension was included. Building the Setup project then generates me an MSI.

Here's the problem: I run the MSI, install my extension (which completes successfully)...

But then when I restart Visual Studio I'd expect to see my new extension installed but there's nothing; no menu items, no buttons, and nothing in the Extension Manager.

I get the feeling that I'm missing something really simple here, but there's no clue in the walkthroughs I've looked at as to what that might be, and I've been essentially banging my head against a wall for the past two hours trying to do it myself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In order for visual studio to discover your extension you must install the extension manifest files to a certain location. Here is more details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/19/how-vsix-extensions-are-discovered-and-loaded-in-vs-2010.aspx